# Uploading file using selenium WebDriver (java) if their is no text-area to send file path

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to upload a file in "dropbox.com" using selenium WebDriver, when i click on choose file it pops up a window automatically, their is no text area to send file path. how to handle this kind of situation?
and in some situation people use Robot class but i did not understand what is the use of it, i read in java documentation but i did not get clear idea, could some one help on this please, help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using sendKeys():**

If the `input type = file` then you can easily use the sendKeys() method and pass the file's absolute path to the `Choose file` control.

```
//Find the element of upload button and send the path
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("datafile"));
element.sendKeys("C:\Users\Easy\Desktop\testfile.txt");
```

**2. Using AutoIT:**

Since the file upload window is a Windows control, you will have to use a Windows automation tool like AutoIT to send your file path. With AutoIT you can create an .au3 file and compile it to a .exe and invoke this exe file from your Selenium script.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your exe file");
```

And the AutoIT code would be:

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload") 
Send("Full path of the document")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

**3. Using Robot class:**

Using Robot class, you can copy the file's absolute path to your clipboard and then paste it into the Windows File upload window.

```
setClipboardData(fileLocation);
//native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: I tried with the AutoIT tool but i could be succeeded. I tried in chrome.