# unable to upload license file using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Problem: Can't upload license file.

When I execute this code, it just opens the file explorer folder and then nothing happens. It doesn't throw any error so I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.

Code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='normal- 
dialog-button file-button mat-raised-button']")));

actions.click();

actions.sendKeys("C:\\20181121_100031_Amazon.lic");
actions.perform();
```

I tried this code too, but it didn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='CHOOSE FILE ']")).sendKeys("C:\\20181121_100031_Amazon.lic");
```

Comment: There is a similar question, I suppose it can work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689572/uploading-file-using-selenium-webdriver-java-if-their-is-no-text-area-to-send

Comment: I tried that code but didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried this code and it works for me: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Upload file']")).sendKeys("C:\\20181121_100031_Amazon.lic");